# Tensorflow visualization for regularization effects

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Are there tools to visualize the various regularization effects on the weights on tf.keras? I am using training histsory of the train and eval data to plot performance (e.g., accuracy, auc, etc.) However, I would like to see the regularization effects on the weights themselves. Any tools out there?

Comment: You can plot the norm of the weights and if you rerun the training many times, the mean and variance. Is that what you're after?

Comment: IMO, the mean and variance of the norm of the weights can give some insight. But I would like to view the weight distribution histogram to gain more insight. Any suggestion for that? Thanks.

Comment: You can retrieve all weights after each epoch using `model.trainable_variables` and perform whatever visualization you are after. Not sure what the point would be though. The variables generally follow a normal distribution and the effect of regularization is to reduce the variance of that distribution.

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks for the explanation. I'll try your suggestion. Which functions do you use for them?

Comment: So far I haven't found any need for inspecting layers' weights so I don't use any functions.